# ruamel.yaml 0.17.16 python3 UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I use python3.5.2, and ruamel.yaml version is 0.17.16,
when I use `ruamel_yaml.dump(content, fp)`, it appeared error

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 434: ordinal not in range(128)"

on ruamel/yaml/emitter.py write_comment function.

And I set `ruamel_yaml.encoding = True`, when read file I also set encoding='UTF-8', it doesn't work.

And I changed to python3.7, There is no UnicodeEncodeError error, but I found generated file has wrong 'utf-8' error.

Does the ruamel.yaml need to match which python version?
Or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please search for the error message, there are lots of similar questions already. Also, your question lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting no error and different results with different Python versions.
AFAICT there is nothing 3.5 or 3.7 specific with regards to handling files.
Although end-of-life Python 3.5 is still supported and tested.

You don't provide much code (you should), but from the error I can tell you try to dump something
with a right single quotation mark (`’`, Unicode code point 2019) .

You should include more of your code so it is clear how the files are opened, and include
on which platform you run your code (Windows). You are as you are most likely
writing to text file  ( `open('somefile.yaml')` ) where you should write to a file opened for binary
( `open('somefile.yaml', 'wb')` )

The `YAML()` instance already has the attribute `.encoding` set to `utf-8` by default,
so setting that again will have no effect.

```
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(text="here comes the unicode quote -> \u2019")
print('python version:', sys.version_info)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml_file = pathlib.Path('somefile.yaml')

# You can open the Path like this, but it is better to have ruamel.yaml do it
# with yaml_file.open('wb') as fp:
#     yaml.dump(data, fp)

yaml.dump(data, yaml_file)

readback = yaml_file.read_bytes()
print('{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(readback[-4], readback[-3], readback[-2]))
```

which gives:

```
python version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
e28099
```

which is the expected UTF-8 encoding of the right single quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I changed 'w' to 'wb', this issue fixed.